# Input not editable in ng-sortable container

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-sortable

I have an issue with input elements within a ng-sortable container. 
The inputs are not editable. however I can attach a click event. The values can be changed via the controller.

Here is a Plunler to illustrate the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/pNJD26eJdkuuzJVA0ys8?p=preview

```
 <div class="sortable-row" as-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="itemsList.items1">
     <div ng-repeat="item in itemsList.items1" as-sortable-item>
         <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{item.Label}}
         <input type="text" ng-model="item.label">//can not be edited
         </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is because your input is **inside** the `as-sortable-item-handle` therefore the clicks events are stopped;

You can try to get your input out of the div like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemsList.items1 track by item.Id" as-sortable-item>
    <div as-sortable-item-handle>{{item.Label}}</div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.Label">
</div>
```

Then you can edit the inputs content freely, hope that helps !

Comment: Taking it out of the 'as-sortable-item-handle' did solve the issue. However dragging only the title is a litte counterintuitive. Will have to add a drag icon or so. Thanks for your help!